# Adode Flash Player offline?

Tags: flash, adobe, offline

Did anyone tried an offline Flash install? I have a Windows Server 2008 VM with no internet access.
Do you know how to do this? Is there any particular .exe for this, or the usual one?

I tried some Google suggestions, but no luck so far...

Comment: do you mean as a browser plugin or standalone binary?

Comment: Standalone. I need it on a VM with no access to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the "standalone" distribution of the flash player here:
https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Choose from the "projector" releases for your matching OS/architecture.